# Printing current WebView page as HTML Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, webview, nsstring

How to I print (or store as a string) the HTML of the current page being displayed in a WebView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this:

```
 NSString *test = [webViewTest stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.outerHTML"];
```

It works.